# Is it possible to use "SELECT COUNT" as a reference to another cell with the "JOIN ON" clause in MySQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I have a problem as follows; Let's say I have 3 tables like this:

tableA

| ID_name | Name | Email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | xx |
| 2 | Betty | xx |
| 3 | Chris | xx |

tableB

| Id_task | id_name | Tasks_submitted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 |

tableC

| Id_C | Task_count | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | E |
| 2 | 1 | D |
| 3 | 2 | C |
| 4 | 3 | B |
| 5 | 4 | A |

Then I execute this query:

```
Select name,COUNT(Tasks_submitted) as TASKS, score
from tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB on tableA.ID_name=tableB.id_name
JOIN tableC ON (SELECT COUNT (Tasks_submitted)) = tableC.Task_count
GROUP BY tableA.ID_name
```

But that doesn't work.

The result I want:

| Name | TASKS | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 3 | B |
| Betty | 2 | C |
| Chris | 0 | E |

Is it possible in SQL to use "SELECT COUNT" or alias as a reference to another table in the JOIN ON clause? Or is there another way to achieve the query result I desire? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate the `tableB` (tasks) data in a [derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), so the count is available for the join:

```
SELECT a.Name, IFNULL(b.cnt, 0) AS TASKS, c.score
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM tableB
    GROUP BY id_name
) b ON a.ID_name = b.id_name
LEFT JOIN tableC c
    ON IFNULL(b.cnt, 0) = c.Task_count;
```

You have not included much of an explanation, so we do not know what the possible values for `Tasks_submitted` are. If it can only be `1` then `COUNT(*)` is slightly more efficient, as it is not null checking the column.

Assuming there is an index on `tableB.id_name`, doing the aggregation on just `tableB` in the derived table should be more efficient than having both `tableA` and `tableB` in the derived table, but test with your data to verify either way.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3pCeXIIL).

Comment: it's work! thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT sub.name, sub.TASKS, t2.score
FROM (
    SELECT name, COUNT(Tasks_submitted) as TASKS
    FROM tableA
    LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.ID_name = tableB.id_name
    GROUP BY tableA.ID_name
) AS sub
LEFT JOIN tableC AS t2 ON sub.TASKS = t2.Task_count;
```